# Refresh ExtJS Grid

Tags: extjs

I have a grid that I want to refresh. But when it refreshes, the fields in the table are not updated, fields are added to the end of the table. How can I make it so that the fields are only updated?

```
theStore.on('load', function () {
            theStore.data.each(function(item, index, totalItems ) {
                 this.getStore().add({
                    type: 'Book',
                    night: item.data['author'],
                    day: item.data['price']
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm right in understanding you- you want to change:

```
this.getStore().add({
 type: 'Book',
 night: item.data['author'],
 day: item.data['price']
});
```

To:

```
this.getStore().loadRawData({
 type: 'Book',
 night: item.data['author'],
 day: item.data['price']
});
```

[See here from the Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadRawData)

> loadRawData( data, [append] ) Loads data via the bound Proxy's reader
>
> Use this method if you are attempting to load data and want to utilize
>   the configured data reader.

Comment: thank you. yes I want something, that does not add the data to grid, only  update the existing data. When i am write this.getStore().loadRawData   in console show errors Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getStore'

Comment: try simply `theStore.loadRawData`

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the store and then calling the reload method.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-reload

Comment: about this: Store.load(); ?